# How to find nearest cluster from a trajectory?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I ran a clustering algorithm DBSCAN on a set historical trajectory dataset which returns a set of clusters. Now, for each incoming new trajectory, I need to find the nearest cluster.

Suppose, I have 10 clusters (c1 to c10) and a trajectory 't'. I want to find the nearest cluster from the trajectory 't'. I saw people use kNN for this purpose, but as I am not fully clear I am asking this question. What is the best/efficient way to do this? I am using python.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: Why is that? I dont understand? What's the problem with the question? @desertnaut

Comment: It's a programming problem? Sorry but I do not agree with you. @desertnaut

Comment: You are very welcome not to agree, *after* you have read the SO *rules & guidelines* (yes, there are such things), some of which have been already provided as a courtesy only for your convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Clustering techniques, such as DBSCAN, generally work slightly differently than other machine learning models. This is because once you fit a model to your historical trajectory dataset, you cannot predict a new trajectory like a traditional classifier or regressor would. This gives you a few options, either:

A) append your new trajectory to your historicals, run clustering again, see what label is assigned (this is very computationally expensive, probably a bad idea)

B) perform clustering on only historicals, use those generated labels to train a classifier, and perform inference on your new trajectory (this has high overhead, but with sufficient data can work pretty well)

C) use some measure of distance between your new trajectory and the mean of each cluster of historical trajectories (this is probably the easiest and fastest, but relies on your knowledge to implement it in a way that provides meaningful results)

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more about calculating the mean of a cluster? Thanks! @pciunkiewicz

Comment: @faring It largely depends on the shape of your data. If your trajectories are `NxM` dimensional, you want to take the set of all `K` trajectories within cluster `C` to form an `NxMxK` array. From this array containing all of the trajectories labeled in that cluster, you take the mean across the appropriate axes to get an output which is `NxM`. If your trajectories are irregularly shaped, you can pad or truncate them as a means of generating a meaningful comparison.